# Efficient way to describe someone employed but not at the place you're talking about

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context

The context

I'm describing a particular type of school: privately-owned, a very specific subject taught, and along with the actual employees of the school, there are "coaches" who currently work doing the same job that the students are currently learning. These coaches are not paid directly a salary by the school, but depending on the amount the school was able to receive for each student hired at any given company, the coach receives a percentage of the amount.

These "coaches" are described in the text now as "...with the guidance of currently-working coaches incentivized on the success of the participants".

I think that describing these coaches as "currently-working" is a little clunky. It doesn't imply that:

- These coaches are currently-working *doing the exact same job*
- These coaches are not actually working *for the school*, as the bonus they receive is not enough to live on

Any ideas? Am I over-thinking this? If you came across that phrase would you understand what it's implying?

Comment: First of all, a bonus is for employees. These are independent contractor coaches as they are not employees of the school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the phrase because you explained the situation, and suggest this rewording:

> ...with coaching from independent experts who are rewarded by the success of the participants.

Because

- "coaches" becomes "coaching", making way for "experts".
- "independent" indicates they are not working directly for the school.
- "rewarded" is less direct than the tacky "incentivized", and how they are paid isn't really relevant.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of thing I was looking for. I was also concerned about "incentivized", and considered replacing it with "invested in", since they aren't getting paid upfront their "investment" is their time spent with the participants. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps then: "...rewarded by their investment in the participants' success."

Comment: Independent is the correct spelling

Comment: coaches are not independent experts....they are employees of the institution or they are contractors.

Comment: Employed, unless they are self- employed usually don’t do independent coaching.  Unless they do it as volunteers. Independent contractors could do all kind of work for others vs. employees only for their employer. Doing the same kind of work means independent contractors specialize in the the same type of work they are doing ( coaching) at school. They are not rewarded or incentivized. They have a contract that spells out compensation for their work  that could include a bonus for student’s performance.

Comment: According to OP, they are. I have rephrased what was stated. A discussion of the contractual arrangements is off topic, both here, and in a prospectus.